# Generating XML files Using CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

i have a questiion about formatting xml files after generating them. Here is my code:

```python
 import csv
 from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
 from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

 root = Element('Solution')
 root.set('version','1.0')
 tree = ElementTree(root)

 head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
 head.set('total_holes', '238')

 description = SubElement(head,'description')


 with open ('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
      current_group = None
      reader = csv.reader(data)
      i = 0
      for row in reader:
          if i > 0:
               x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
               if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                   current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

               information = SubElement (current_group, 'hole',{'collar':', '.join((x1,y1,z1)),
                                                     'toe':', '.join((x2,y2,z2)),
                                                     'cost':    cost})
          i+=1
```

Which produces the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Solution version="1.0">
     -<DrillHoles total_holes="238">
           -<description>
                 -<hole hole_id="1">
                        <hole toe="5797.82, 3061.01, 2576.29" cost="102.12" collar="5720.44, 3070.94, 2642.19"/></hole>
```

that is just a part of the xml file but it is enough to serve this purpose.
There are many things i would like to change, first is i would like the toe,cost, and collar to be on different lines like so:

```
    <collar>0,-150,0</collar>
    <toe>69.9891,-18.731,-19.2345</toe>
    <cost>15</cost>
```

and i would like it to be in the order of collar then toe then cost shown above.
Furthermore, in the xml file it displays : "hole toe ="5797.82, 3061.01, 2576.29", how do i get rid of the hole? Yea thats about it, i am really new to this python thing so go easy on me. haha

Comment: If you want to be the `toe`, `cost`, and `collar` to be *elements* instead of *attributes*, create `SubElement`s for them and them to the `current_group`.

Comment: Also, you very probably do not want comma separated values like `0,-150,0`. That's explicitly not what XML has been designed for. You want to serialize your data, not a serialized representation of your data.